# Any best practices on whether to access class instance members directly or pass state as parameters to a class method?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
Foo
{
     private int _instanceData;

    // Do this?
    private void Bar1(int instanceData) { // some work using 'instanceData' }

    // Or this?
    private void Bar1( ) { // some work using '_instanceData' }
}
```

Comment: Let me guess, you're a Ruby programmer?

Answer (score 6):

If a method already has access to the relevant information as part of the state of the object - and unambiguously so - then I think it would be highly confusing to *also* pass it in as an argument to the method.

Most of the point of instance methods is to associate behaviour with the state of the object. If you're passing in the information the method needs, you would be better of making the method itself static to make it *clear* that you're not using the existing state of the object. I'd probably just make it an instance method in the fist place though.

Why would you *want* to pass in the information via a parameter, when you already have access to it via the instance state?

Comment: I guess this comes down to finding common code and putting that in static utility classes. For example, a class Circle could have a method Draw() which relies on the radius of the Circle. You might want a Draw method that is more generic that takes a radius as a parameter: Draw(int radius) and then in your Circle class just call this method with the class instance variable value for radius.

Comment: I might make `Draw(int radius)` a private static method of Circle, in this case.  Though I think `Draw` would need both the radius and the position.

Comment: @user597934: But then that method `Draw` shouldn't be an instance method of `Circle`, because it's not using the state of the `Circle`. Where would the benefit be? Now an instance method on Draw might use a method of a *different* class, e.g. `GraphicsContext.DrawCircle` and pass in its radius, but that's a very different matter.

Answer (score 2):

If the property or field belongs to the same class and you don't want external data to be passed to the method, then there is no need to request that information from the developer and rather call it inside the class instance itself.